# What to do with Questions that remain unanswered while they have already been answered?

Tags: discussion

Although the user indicated that [this question](https://devops.stackexchange.com/q/2311/210) has been answered and was asked to post an answer this question keeps on returning into the unanswered tab. How to prevent that this list is growing and growing while some of these questions have already been answered?

My suggestion is to close these questions after three months as inactive. What do other people think about this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We don't close question as inactive, what prevents this question of being deleted is the two upvotes it has. I'm tempted to close as unclear what you're asking and 'et the roomba delete it, or to just delete it as no one but the author can answer it.

I think the author has left it as is because I did close it too quickly while closing old still unclear question, this one was recent but I didn't give a try to comment and wait before closing.

Last resort for those question could be to flag for moderator attention and explain there's things missing and no reaction from the author.